# What's the difference between "the killing machine" and "the machine that's killing"

Tags: grammar, word-order

Are they interchangeable? If so, can I apply it for every sentence that conveys the similar meaning like "a toy that is moving" to "a moving toy"? I've never seen someone ask about it or feel the need to address it. I once asked someone about this and they said it's a little complex.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Taking your two examples exactly as written...

- "The killing machine" would be a machine that *can* kill.
- "The machine that's killing" would be a machine that *is* currently killing.

When a compound noun contains an -ing verb it is a gerund and normally denotes either its *purpose* (for example, a *carving knife* or a *printing press*), or some action that it carries out whilst in use only (for example, a *spinning top*). Only when you use an -ing verb as a verb is it denoting an action in the continuous tense.

You could say "*the machine that kills*" and that would mean a machine that is capable of killing, but it doesn't quite carry the idea that killing is its *intended* purpose quite like "the killing machine". It could just mean a machine for some other purpose that is deadly.

Comment: Like a coffee cup is a cup that's made for coffee or used for coffee, even if there isn't any coffee in it right now.

Comment: A couple of minor technicalities with this answer, the first definition also encapsulates the second.  "The killing machine" could be the machine that is killing right now, and it could also be a machine which is unable to kill, such as a broken killing machine or e.g. a gun without bullets.  Or a gun which has shot the last living thing, which is still a killing machine but now defunct.  The gerund could indicates its purpose, despite it being unable to fulfil its purpose.

Comment: There's also the figurative sense in that you might describe something that isn't a literal machine as a "*killing machine*".  E.g. a vicious animal or a well trained and/or armed fighter.  "*The machine that's killing*" is not a common phrase in that way.

Comment: A "killing machine" could also be a machine whose purpose is to kill, whether it is able to or not.

Comment: Just to further complicate things, with a bit of poetic licence, as in the lyrics of Deep Purple's "Highway Star", killing machine can be a term of admiration... the best, or ultimate kind, of something. So if killing is an extreme, irrevocable action, then a killing machine is "better" than some other machine that doesn't reach this extreme.

Comment: @DominicCronin: though mostly a technicality, Highway Star, calls it a "killer machine", not a "killing machine".

Comment: I think the complicating factor mentioned in other comments is specifically that "machine" is often used euphamistically to describe something that is (or seems) purpose built to accomplish something well, or to an uncanny degree of consistency. "Did you see Steph Curry in the game last night? That guy is a machine!" In cases where the function of the euphamistic "machine" might not be clear from context, or perhaps for emphasis, I've seen the gerund thrown in. It might be useful to expand the answer to discuss the euphamistic use of "machine" as potentially relevant.

Comment: For example, the Terminator is a "machine that kills", whereas Rambo is a "killing machine". (to be fair, the Terminator would probably qualify as both)

Comment: @Blackhawk I don't dispute that a person may be metaphorically called 'a machine', but that is just one of many uses of the word, literal and figurative. Any kind of functional 'system' can be called a machine. But the OP's question was not about that - just the sentence structure. They even used the example of "a moving toy" in the body of their question but I don't see anybody suggesting that might mean a toy that poignantly stirs the emotions.

Comment: I suppose you could say that's a gerund acting as an adjective, and I guess that's the most likely interpretation with "killing machine", but in the general case, it's usually going to be a present participle which basically means the same thing as the relative clause. "The running man is fast" "These scissors are broken, where are the working ones?"

Comment: In HNQ right now, "How could one outsmart a tracking implant?"

Comment: @Astralbee I suppose I'm saying that if "the killing machine" is the actual phrase the OP cares about, is there any other interpretation than euphemistic? And if so, maybe it is worth explaining that to the OP as a sort of P.S. at the bottom of the answer (maybe add a line and a second header or something to avoid confusion that it's answering the specific question the OP asked).

Answer (score 2):

### Purpose

If the purpose of the machine is to kill, then it is a Killing Machine.

If the purpose of the machine is to *not kill*, but kills anyway (due to defective design, manufacture or maintenance, or incompetent users), then it's a machine that kills (and makes lawyers rich).

Comment: This is the better answer, methinks, because I think the _purpose_ of the machine is fundamental.

Comment: @TonyEnnis I cover the purpose aspect quite extensively in my answer. But the direct answer to the OP's question is the difference between two constructions, and purpose plays no part in the difference.

Comment: @Astralbee while you are *grammatically* correct in a reductionist manner, language is more than reductionist grammar.  For example, Destructor (the use of which is considered a war crime across the galaxy) is a killing machine, whereas automobiles are machines that kill.